# How to apply a transformation to each element matched by jQuery and meeting some condition

Tags: jquery

I have a list of checkboxes. I want to get the text of the next element from each checked box, and collect those into a new list.

I was just wandering if something like this is possible:

```
var checked_all = $('.brand-chk').each().is(':checked') ? $(this).next().text() : continue;
```

Practically, I want to do this:

```
var checked_all = [];
$('.brand-chk').each(function(e) {
   if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      checked_all.push($(this).next().text());
   }
});
```

As it is, the syntax is incorrect and `continue` is not acceptable there... Could this be done?

Comment: Why are you trying to super-obfuscate your code?

Comment: Do you mean `$('.brand-chk:checked').each()`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit , I really don't know, I sensed there was somethinf which could reduce the code, as I tend to prefer short code especially client side.. And blgt just presented me with the best alternative, which I cant believe It didn't come to my mind. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could chain together some jQuery functions to get something like this:

```
var checked_all = $('.brand-chk') // match all checkboxen
  .filter(':checked') // now let's only look at checked ones
  .map(function() { 
    return $(this).next().text(); // take next().text() from each element
  });
```

But since `.next()`, like most jQuery manipulators, works on each element in the matched list and returns a list of the resulting elements, you can just do:

```
var checked_all = $('brand-chk')
  .filter(':checked') 
  .next() // get list of next() applied to each element in the original list
  .map(function() { return $(this).text(); });
```

We can move the `filter` inside the original selector for some performance gain, especially if there are a lot of unchecked boxes:

```
var checked_all = $('brand-chk:checked') 
  .next() 
  .map(function() { return $(this).text(); });
```

Finally we can use some JS trickery to avoid declaring an anonymous function:

```
var checked_all = $('brand-chk:checked').next().map($.fn.text);
```

But I'm not sure this is more readable than the previous version.

Comment: I have to admit, you know your jquery! Awesome, thanks a heaps